# Install Vagrant 2.2.6 on OSX 10.15.2 Catalina

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

How can vagrant be installed on OSX 10.15.2?

After installing virtualbox and vagrant:

```
brew cask install virtualbox   # installs version 6.1
brew cask install vagrant      # installs version 2.2.6
```

I run into this error when starting vagrant:

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed
that is not supported by this version of Vagrant. Please install one of
the supported versions listed below to use Vagrant:

4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 6.0

A Vagrant update may also be available that adds support for the version
you specified. Please check www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html to download
the latest version.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant 2.2.6 doesn't support VirtualBox 6.1. You can install VirtualBox 6.0 (which is supported) with an older version of the virtualbox cask script, like this:

```
brew cask install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/7e703e0466a463fe26ab4e253e28baa9c20d5f36/Casks/virtualbox.rb
```

Vagrant 2.2.7 will include support for virtualbox 6.1 but is at the time of writing not released yet: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11249

Comment: any way to install vagrant 2.2.5 on mac?